# Can't add/edit bookmarks in firefox 119.0 on 22.04

Tags: firefox, mouse

I can't add or edit bookmarks in firefox 119.0 on my 22.04 system.  If I bookmark a page with ^D then an Edit Bookmark popup appears but as soon as the mouse enters it it disappears.

The address bar has a red star at its right side showing the page is bookmarked, but if you click on that the same Edit Bookmark popup appears and then disappears when you mouse over to it.

Clicking on the the hamburger icon pops up the long list of options, but as soon as you mouse down to it it too disappears... unless you hold the mouse button down whole moving, then the popup stays visible and you can use it.

**I turned off all my Extensions but it made no difference.**

There are lots of similar problems, like when I try to add an extension (Simple Translate for example): if I click on Add to Firefox then the throbber starts throbbing and a popup window asks "Add Simple Translate?" with two buttons, [Cancel] and [Add], but if you click on either one the popup disappears, the throbber keeps throbbing and nothing happens.  I finally realized that if I background the tab then I can see the popup again, waiting for me to click Cancel/Add although I already did.  Repeat as many times as you want, it will never install.

I had lots of problems like this on my old 18.04 system, supposedly an incompatibility in some library, but 18.04 supported had ended and I was told I was SOL and needed to update to a more recent Ubuntu...  which I did, but still having lots of problems like this.